# PHP Database SELECT

Tags: php

I want to show me from the database ID and User (from table users), this is my code but i keep getint an errors.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','S024_V7','S024_V7','S024_V7');

$sql ="SELECT id, user FROM Users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> ID: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["User"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Errors:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '""' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /Projekti/S024_V7/index.php on line 9

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Projekti/S024_V7/index.php on line 7
0 results

Comment: Line 7 is a comment and thus can't have a `Trying to get property of non-object` notice. Are you sure the line numbers match your code sample?

Comment: If your column is `user` instead of what you wrote as `User` in the loop, then that's an issue. Your `$row["User"]` is being interpreted as `$row[""]` which could cause that error.

Comment: You can not have both this error and the notice at the same time, that is impossible.

Comment: Sorry all, i had to transalte it from my native language to english so you can understand it.

Comment: You didn't given anyone a chance to solve this. This will only benefit you and nobody else.

Comment: @urosv you code looks fine but you are using double quotes in `echo` statement

Comment: Actually not. This will help at least 20 of my college students to finish there home work. @-Fred-ii- Thank you all.

Comment: @urosv find my solution and try to run in your application

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have used double quotes `""` instead of single `''` try this code it will solve your problem

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','S024_V7','S024_V7','S024_V7');

$sql ="SELECT id, user FROM Users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> ID: ". $row['id']. " - Name: ". $row['user']."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved:

```
    $sql = "SELECT idkorisnik, ime FROM korisnik";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> ID: ". $row["idkorisnik"]. " - Ime: ". $row["ime"]. " " . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You posted this `SELECT id, user` in your question, not what you posted in the answer. That is a total curve ball.

Comment: Had to translate it to English, so people can uderstand it.

Comment: You didn't given anyone a chance to solve this. This will only benefit you and nobody else; this being the same I comment I left under your question and it was closed respectively.

Comment: @-fred-ii- thank you for you comment, and for the help. Will try my best!